# Read JSON data from UTF-8 encoded byte string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a script that sends a JSON UTF-8 encoded Byte string to a socket. (A github project: https://github.com/alios/raildriver). Now I'm writing the python script that needs to read the incoming data. Right now I can receive the data and print it to the terminal. With the following script: https://www.binarytides.com/code-telnet-client-sockets-python/

Output:

```
data = '{"Current": 117.42609405517578, "Accelerometer": -5.394751071929932, "SpeedometerKPH": 67.12493133544922, "Ammeter": 117.3575210571289, "Amp": 117.35590362548828, "Acceleration": -0.03285316377878189, "TractiveEffort": -5.394751071929932, "Effort": 48.72163772583008, "RawTargetDistance": 3993.927734375, "TargetDistanceBar": 0.9777777791023254, "TargetDistanceDigits100": -1.0, "TargetDistanceDigits1000": -1.0}'
```

The problem is that I can't find how to read the JSON array. For example read `"Ammeter"` and return its value `117.357521057289` to a new variable.

All the data is being received in the variable `data`

The code I have right now:

```
decodedjson = data.decode('utf-8')
dumpedjson = json.dumps(decodedjson)
loadedjson = json.loads(dumpedjson)
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

You are **encoding** to JSON then decoding again. SImply *not encode*, remove the second line:

```
decodedjson = data.decode('utf-8')
loadedjson = json.loads(decodedjson)
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer, you don't actually have to decode from UTF-8, as the `json.loads()` function knows how to deal with UTF-encoded JSON data directly. The same applies to Python 2:

```
loadedjson = json.loads(data)
```

Demo using Python 3.7:

```
>>> data = b'{"Current": 117.42609405517578, "Accelerometer": -5.394751071929932, "SpeedometerKPH": 67.12493133544922, "Ammeter": 117.3575210571289, "Amp": 117.35590362548828, "Acceleration": -0.03285316377878189, "TractiveEffort": -5.394751071929932, "Effort": 48.72163772583008, "RawTargetDistance": 3993.927734375, "TargetDistanceBar": 0.9777777791023254, "TargetDistanceDigits100": -1.0, "TargetDistanceDigits1000": -1.0}'
>>> loadedjson = json.loads(data)
>>> loadedjson['Ammeter']
117.3575210571289
```

Comment: *What* error? Where? Did you verify that you have Python 3.6 or an older version?

Comment: decodedjson = data.decode('utf-8')
loadedjson = json.loads(decodedjson)
print loadedjson['Ammeter']There is an error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
     loadedjson = json.loads(decodedjson)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'

Comment: You are using python 2 then. Without a proper sample we can’t help you then. We need more than a single print output

Comment: @RubinNederlof: put differently: we don't know how `data` is being loaded, if this is being executed in a loop, etc. The specific `data` value you have *there* differs from what you posted here. Perhaps there is extra data in it or this loop iteration produced an empty `data` value. Without more context on how to reproduce the error, we can't help more than what we've done so far.

Comment: The data is being send by a github project to read data from a simulation game: https://github.com/alios/raildriver. The data is being received by this script: https://www.binarytides.com/code-telnet-client-sockets-python/. I hope this is the information you need.

Comment: No, not really. We'd need a minimal script that reproduces the problem, not the whole system.

Comment: Just updated to Python 3.6, now I am receiving another errror: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ','. The code that produces the error was the code you suggested:              
loadedjson = json.loads(data)                print(loadedjson['Ammeter'])

Comment: @RubinNederlof: again, this is an issue with the data you are loading, not how you load it. We can't debug this for you, not without a small piece of code to reproduce the issue. Your JSON appears incomplete.

Comment: def updatedValues(self):
        updates = dict()
        
        info = self.locoInfo
        if not info: return updates

        self.dataLock.acquire()
        
        for key in info.keys:
            i = info.keys.index(key)
            val = self.api.GetControllerValue(i,0)
            if ((key in self.values) and (self.values[key] == val)):
                continue;
            else:
                updates[key] = val
self.values[key] = val
self.dataLock.release()
return updates updates = self.updatedValues(); self.broadcastClients(json.dumps(updates) + "\n")

Comment: This is not something that can be communicated or solved in comments, sorry. Post a *new question*, with a minimal example that reproduces the issue. We don't necessarily need to see the exact code that produces the JSON, for example.